# Как с помощью AJAX прочитать, и затем сохранить текстовый файл на сервере?

Tags: ajax

Нужно взять текстовые данные по ссылке www...\[text.txt](http://text.txt), и после произведения действий с ними записать их обратно. Возможно ли это сделать только с помощью AJAX без применения PHP?

Comment: Нет.

Comment: @ROOT, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, если на сервере настроить обработку [`HTTP PUT`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) запроса. Тогда HTTP GET'ом вы будете скачивать файл в браузер, редактировать, а затем, тоже с помощью ajax-запроса, но метода PUT – например, [средствами jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) – загружать обратно. Никакого PHP : )

Answer (score 1):

Можно без применения PHP, но нужно использовать тогда другие серверные сценарии (JSP, ASP и так далее). Просто с помощью AJAX это сделать не получится.